# There are $40$ MPs of party $A$, $35$ MPs of party $B$ and $25$ MPs of party $C$ . How many teams of three are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

*There are $40$ MPs of party A, $35$ MPs of party B and $25$ MPs of party C. We need to create **$10$ distinct teams of MPs** made up exactly by **$1$ member of each party** ( $10$ teams of $3$ Mps each). For example an eligible teams is $(A1,B2,C2)$. In how many ways can we do that?*
Note: An MP can be a part of at most one team.

> My solution: We need to form $10$ teams , each one needs one member of each party $\rightarrow$ we need $10$ Mps of each party. We pick 10 from party A in $C(40,10)$ ways, independently $10$ from party B in $C(35,10)$ and $C(25,10)$ ways from party C $\rightarrow C(40,10)*C(35,10)*C(25,10)$. Now , we need to seperate them into teams. We put Mps of party A in one straight line , we add next to every A Mp, a B one and right after a C one but we can rearrange B's and C's in $10!$ each , so we can create $10!^2$ different teams .Final answer: $C(40,10)*C(35,10)*C(25,10) * 10!^2$.
>
> > Can you suggest any other solutions?

Comment: Does party A have $45$ MPs or $40$ MPs? The question says $45$ MPs but your working is for $40$ MPs. Also, why would it be ${(10!)}^2$ and not ${(10!)}^3$?

Comment: @badjohn meant to say members of parliament,

Comment: @math lover it won't (10!)³ because the teams arrangement don't matter . We just need to make the groups.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe well, imagine that every party has only 3 members , an arrangement of A's could be (A2,A1,A3) , for B's (B1,B2,B3) and for c's (C1,C2,C3) . Now try what I suggested: make 3! rearrangements for B's and for C's . If you combine those with A's you create every possible team. If you did the same for A's you could count multiple times , for example : with the first arrangements you create teams (A2,B1,C1) (A1,B2,C2), (A3,B3,C3) . but if you rearrange those (A1,A2,A3) (B2,B1,B3)(C2,C1,C3) you count those teams twice

Comment: @TheSilverDoe (continued) think about it also like that : check the first teams we made (A2,B1,C1) (A1,B2,C2), (A3,B3,C3). All we do , is change the positions of B's in 3! and change the positions of C's there

Comment: I'm unclear on the question: when you say you need to create $10$ teams, are these teams allowed to overlap in members? Say $(A1, B1, C1)$ and $(A1, B1, C2)$. These are distinct teams, though two of MPs are shared by both.

Comment: @PaulSinclair note that :  an Mp can be a member of at most one team

Comment: Note that is additional information. It does not follow from either of the phrases you made bold. the first of which just says that two teams cannot have *all three* members the same, and the second of which just says that any one team can only have 1 member from each party. Neither says that an MP cannot work on two teams, provided that the teams differ in some other member. Are you sure you are correct about the intent?